# Can i animate alpha of UIBlurEffectView?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiblureffect

Since iOS 8 Apple provided easier way to make blur. But can i animate its appearance?

```
 CSDTimelineCell* headerCell = (CSDTimelineCell*)[self.timelineTabel cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.headerIndexPath];
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *bluredEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[bluredEffectView setFrame:headerCell.bounds];
[bluredEffectView setHidden: YES];
[headerCell addSubview:(UIView *)bluredEffectView];
[UIView transitionWithView:bluredEffectView
                  duration:3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    bluredEffectView.hidden = NO;
                } completion:nil];
```

Setting 0 alpha value is deprecated for this class.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`UIVisualEffectView` is a hack in the Apple framework. It's not an overlapping layer, it completely replaces the layers behind itself by processing them. It won't be possible to change its `alpha`.

However, it should be possible to use `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` transition but you have to use it correctly. The transition takes a snapshot of a view before changes then takes a snapshot of a view after changes and then animates the difference. You need to give it a view that encompasses all the changes:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:headerCell
                  duration:3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    bluredEffectView.hidden = NO;
                } completion:nil];
```

(I haven't tested this but it might work)

Comment: it worked, but sometimes app is tend to crush with no alert in console